# How do I change the desktop cube into a sphere or cylinder?

Tags: cube

I have the desktop cube enabled and everything, and I've watched several tutorials on it. But when I go to the cube settings in compiz I don't have the option to make it a sphere or cylinder. Is there something additional I need to install in order to make that work or what?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure you have all the extra plugins installed as well

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

Then you just have to enable it in the compiz settings
[image: enabling cylinder plugin in compiz]